# Difference between Spring Batch StepScope class and annotation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

Can someone explain what is the difference between the Spring Batch's:

[StepScope](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Scope.html) Annotation

and

[StepScope](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/core/scope/StepScope.html) Class

*Other than the fact one is an annotation another is a class.*

What is the use of the `StepScope` class ?

I have an idea of what the `StepScope` annotation is used for but what is the use for the class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use StepScope class, it is the implementation allowing the Spring container to handle lifetime of bean declared with Step scope (annotated with @StepScope). Basically the implementation will return the same bean inside a step and return a new instance for an other step.